# ingreso de datos en array al azar JAVA

Tags: java, array, random

como están?, explico mi problema, tengo una matriz de 4x4 y deseo llenarla con 4 valores, pero que estos tomen una posición al azar en la matriz, por ejemplo el valor 1, que quede en la posición matriz[0][3] y el valor2 en la posición matriz[1][2], estoy con los dos clásicos for para moverme por el array y a los valores de "j" e "i" le había puesto un random, pero no funciono, dejo código adjunto por si ayuda en algo, de antemano muchas gracias.

```
    //bound tiene un valor de 5
    public void LlenarMatriz(int bound){
    int valor = 0;
    boolean encontrado = false;
    
        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < valores.length && !encontrado; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < valores[i].length; j++) {
                valores[i+r.nextInt(valores.length-3)][j+r.nextInt(valores[0].length-3)] = r.nextInt(bound);
    //esto lo tengo para ver en pantalla que valores me estaba tomando y poder ver si funciona
                System.out.println(valores[i][j]+"SOY EL VALOR");
    
                valor++;
                if(valor < 2){
                    encontrado = true;
                }
            
            }
        }
       
}
```

edit//
Me olvide poner que ya me funciona lo de que sean solo 4 valores, el problema es que se ingresen al azar en el array.

Comment: empecemos por el principio.. que sentido tiene recorrer toda una matriz de 16 posiciones para que en cada caso, al llegar a una posicion, se le asigne a otra celda que nada que ver, un valor que nada que ver con lo que se recorre... si queres meterle 4 valores a una matriz, generas 4 posiciones xy (con el random, como hiciste) y le pones a mano el valor que queres... no tenes que hacer mas que eso...

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, o aprovechas que generas las 4 posiciones aleatorias en un bucle for y les asignas el valor de `i` directamente y ya tienes tus 4 números randomizados sin recorrer todo el array innecesariamente

Comment: Los valores de la matriz pueden repetirse ej si en [1,3] el valor es 4, en [2,3] puede ser 4 tambien

Comment: Pues genéralo al azar al igual que las posiciones. Pero haz caso a @gbianchi, no tiene nada de sentido recorrer un array... si no vas a usar la posición en la que estás!! Para eso haz un bucle de i<4, y en cada iteración generas las 2 posiciones aleatorias y un valor aleatorio, ya está. Es lo mismo que estás haciendo ahora, pero sin necesidad de hacer comprobaciones raras ni restas extrañas, ni usar flags, nada. Necesitas unicamente 3 valores aleatorios, y obtenerlos 4 veces. Para qué quieres más?

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias, de verdad nunca se me paso por la cabeza algo así por la cabeza

Comment: @Benito-B también a ti gracias, y perdón soy muuuy nuevo en todo esto.

Comment: No te preocupes, todos empezamos en algún momento. Una cosa: no intentes hacer las cosas más complicadas de lo que son! He perdido incontables horas enfrentándome a problemas que yo mismo me creaba intentando reinventar la rueda. El mejor consejo que jamás me dieron: ***Cuanto menos código escribas, menos errores cometerás***!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí dos posibles soluciones.

La primera genera un número para cada cuadrícula, los ordena aleatoriamente y luego al crear la cuadrícula solo añade aquellos que están por debajo del bound.

```java
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 4x4 grid
        int maxY = 4;
        int maxX = 4;

        int[][] valores = new int[maxX][maxY];

        int defaultNumber = 0;
        int bound = 5;
        List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, maxY * maxX).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);

        for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < valores[i].length; j++) {

                int number = numbers.remove(0);

                if (number >= bound) {
                    valores[i][j] = defaultNumber;    
                } else {
                    valores[i][j] = number;
                }

                System.out.print(valores[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

No muy eficiente pero curioso...

El otro es generar un `Set` de coordenadas. Dado que el set se asegurará de que no haya dos objetos iguales (no te olvides de implementar equals en la tupla!)

```java
class Demo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 4x4 grid
        int maxY = 4;
        int maxX = 4;

        int[][] valores = new int[maxX][maxY];

        int defaultNumber = 0;
        int bound = 5;
        

        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Set<Point> generated = new LinkedHashSet<Point>();
        while (generated.size() < bound)
        {
            Integer x = r.nextInt(maxX);
            Integer y = r.nextInt(maxY);
            generated.add(new Point(x, y));
        }

        Iterator<Point> it = generated.iterator();
        int z = 1;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Point point = it.next();
            valores[point.x][point.y] = z;
            z++;
        }
 

        for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < valores[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(valores[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mas eficiente ya que no recorre toda la parilla sino solo aquellas posiciones que hay que llenar.